# problem citation (?) in journal submission system

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, citing, journal-publishing

when I submit source tex files to springer journal from their website. I click to generate pdf from uploaded source then I faced following problem:

I have a problem in referencing, I can't see the correct citation. they appeared as question marks (?)

> like this (?) instead of (Morris 2010)

Although I uploaded both .bib & .bbl files. the following are the files:

[image]

Comment: yes I tried building many time

Comment: Did you try with "inputing" the bbl as bibitem instead? Might work better than .bib and .bst

Comment: the deadline is very soon, could you give me very quickly way?

Comment: when I build them on my pc it worked
but on their website it didn't work, and they provide only pdf, there are no log or blg ?

Comment: Open your `.bbl` file, copy everything and replace your `\bibliography` command with the content (N.B.: If there is an error the editorial manager will write the `log` into the resulting PDF and you can find out what went wrong by looking at it. In the next attempt **do not forget to rename your  `.tex` file**  e.g `templatev2.tex`)

Comment: I had similar problem, it worked once I cleaned my `.bib` file of **comments** starting with the `%` character and **non-standard fields** with names such as `Bdsk-Url-1`. These had been autogenerated by _BibDesk_. I did not upload the `.bbl` file. Additionally, I uploaded a PDF version of my manuscript, which also shows up in the autogenerated PDF. I manipulated the order of the autogenerated PDF, so my PDF showed up first by giving it order 1, marking it as manuscript, and naming it `Article.pdf` (In alphabetic order `Article.pdf` shows up before `Manuscript.tex` or `template.tex`).

Comment: If you checked the Elsevier tex file template, you will see this:
%% If you have bibdatabase file and want bibtex to generate the
%% bibitems, please use
%%
%%  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
%%  \bibliography{<your bibdatabase>}

%% else use the following coding to input the bibitems directly in the
%% TeX file.

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

%% \bibitem{label}
%% Text of bibliographic item

\bibitem{}

\end{thebibliography}
So, as Mr. @Mohamed Vall mentioned, copy all bbl content to the tex file between 
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{#}
\end{thebibliography}